# Cannot find CPU frequency of Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine, prometheus

I want to monitor system and application metrics with Prometheus of a VM instance (Debian) on Google Compute Engine. Among them is the CPU frequency, which Prometheus scrapes from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`. However this does not exist.

I also checked `watch -n 0.1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i mhz"`, which is constant. Furthermore, I can see results with GCP's Monitoring tab, but I need a more fine-grained interval than 1 minute.

Does anyone know how I can expose the CPU frequency to Prometheus?

Cheers,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Compute Engine runs in virtualized environment, that's why `/cpufreq` is unavailable and why tools like `hwinfo`, `dmidecode` and `lscpu` will give static reads regardless of load.

The workaround is to use [Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3#metrics) to pull CPU utilization data at the interval you want.